# SQLite, Just wonderig if Im going in the right direction

Tags: sql, sqlite

The library would like  to know the number of times a customer has an overdue fee and has a total overdue fee greater or equal to $5. I then must sort the output by the ‘Number of times overdue’ in descending order then by the ‘Total overduefee ’ in descending order. << Question

What I Have So Far:

```
SELECT FirstName || ' ' || LastName AS "Full Name", (LoanID) AS "Number of Times Overdue", (OverdueFee) AS "Total OverdueFee"
FROM Customer NATURAL JOIN Loan
WHERE OverdueFee >= 5.00
ORDER BY LoanID DESC, OverdueFee DESC;
```

Am i heading in the right direction, ill attach a screenshot of the database Im working with.

Just wanna make sure I also state this is just using a downloaded dbscheme, its not for any actual job purposes, just learning.

Thanks[Database Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/344Au.png)

Comment: Natural join... Forget about that construction, it's for theory only - not to be used in practice.

Comment: I would expect group by, sum and count...